# Update UITableViewCell height after asynchronously loading content

Tags: uitableview, asynchronous, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm using a framework to asynchronously load images (Pinterest's `PINRemoteImage`) in combination with a `UITableView`. On one of my `UITableViewCell`s I have such an image and I first initialize it with a placeholder and it's then later replaced with the real image. I don't know the real image's dimensions at time of loading and therefore the placeholder's dimensions and the ones of the real image may be different.

Using KVO, I watch the `UIImageView`'s `image` property and when it's re-set to the real image, I adjust the the view's height constraint to the appropriate size. This directly shows when I first see the image. It has the appropriate size.

The cell's `contentView` however, does not update it's height to fit around the image (and the other views) properly until the cell get's dequeued a second time. Only then is has the cell the appropriate height.

I assume that I have to tell the table or the cell itself that it needs to update the layout manually. But between all the `layout…` functions I'm not quite sure which to use where right now.

So, where's the best way to make the cell update it's height to the updated image height? Other answers to similar questions on SO suggest to reload the cell, but that seems a bit too much to me. And I'd have to build a callback from the cell (where the image lives) to the table itself which could then trigger the reload.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a good solution for that?